# Code: 0x80073CFB downloading my own app from Microsoft Store

Tags: windows-store, xaf, desktop-bridge

I submitted a private windows app to Microsoft Store.
The app is c# framework 4.7.2 with Entity Framework, XAF and makes use of the Desktop Bridge.
When I try to install the app I get the above error code.
I have been able to install previous versions of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I clicked  the link "Get More Information About Faster Downloads."  and turned off the attempt to use other nearby pcs.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue for my own app on Microsoft Store suddenly. Turning off "Get More Information About Faster Downloads" doesn't help.

According to Ian Zheng from Microsoft, [the code 0x80073CFB means that the provided package is already installed, and reinstallation of the package was blocked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/382945/code-0x80073cfb.html).

I just realised that my app was installed under another Windows account on the same PC. After I deleted it, the installation works again.

Hope this help anyone who has similar issue.